# count frequency of unigrams along with a column

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have code as below

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# dictionary of lists 
dict = {'name':["a1", "b2", "c2", "d3"], 
        'degree': ["We explained to customer how correct fees (100) were charged. Account balance was too low", "customer was late in paying fees and we have to charge fine", "customer's credit score was too low and we have to charge higher interest rate", "customer complained a lot and didnt listen to our explanation. I had to escalate the call"], 
        'score':[90, 40, 80, 98]} 

# creating a dataframe from a dictionary  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
print (df)

import nltk
nltk.download("popular")
from string import punctuation
import re


from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

stopword = stopwords.words('english')
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()


from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
snowball_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')

!pip install contractions
import contractions

def clean_text(text):
    t = contractions.fix(text)#not working

    t= t.lower().split()
    t = [(re.sub(r'[^a-z ]', '', ch)) for ch in t]#remove everything other than a-z
    t= [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in t]
    t=[snowball_stemmer.stem(word) for word in t]
    t=[word for word in t if word not in stopword]




    return t

df["answer"]=df['degree'].apply(clean_text)

display (df)




name    degree  score   answer
0   a1  We explained to customer how correct fees (100...   90  [explain, custom, correct, fee, , charg, accou...
1   b2  customer was late in paying fees and we have t...   40  [custom, wa, late, pay, fee, charg, fine]
2   c2  customer's credit score was too low and we hav...   80  [custom, credit, score, wa, low, charg, higher...
3   d3  customer complained a lot and didnt listen to ...   98  [custom, complain, lot, listen, explan, escal,...
```

from the newly created column, we can see that word custom occurs in all 4 rows (even if a word occurs twice in a cell, i would like to count it as 1). SO i would like to create a dataframe where first column will show name, unigram, score, frequency of unigram

so resulting dataframe should look like below. I want this for all the unigrams. How could i do the same?

```
a1 custom 90 4
b2 custom 40 4
c3 custom 80 4
d4 custom 98 4
```

## update 1

if is there a way to add std deviation of column 3rd column, by grouping similar values from 2nd column? in this case i would like to calculate std dev of (90, 40, 80 and 98) and display on each row where column 2 has value 'custom' and do this for all values in 2nd column

Comment: can you post complete few rows of final df with data. Unigram is taken from last column list?

Comment: yes, the column "answer" , i have pasted few rows at the end

Comment: the count should be done for each word from `answer` list and for each row of this column?

Comment: yes, please also look at my update1

Comment: can you post single row of data ]full row] and expected result for that row with all words?